# Can a class implement an interface and an abstract method with the same name but has different return types?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have an interface and an abstract class, both have a method with the same name, and no arguments but different return types. The interface returns a `System.Object`, while the abstract class returns an instance of the derived class. Can I implement both in my derived class with a single implementation? Here are they:

```
public abstract class BaseAbstract
{
    public abstract BaseAbstract Clone();
}

public interface ICloneable
{
    object Clone();
}

public class Derived : BaseAbstract, ICloneable
{
}
```

I tried multiple approaches and the only solution I have is to have two different implementations, like so:

```
public class Derived : BaseAbstract, ICloneable
{
    public override BaseAbstract Clone() => new Derived()
    {
        // Some cloning logic ....
    };

    object ICloneable.Clone() => this.Clone();
}
```

Is there a way to implement the method just once?

NOTE: BaseAbstract cannot be changed as it's legacy code and is practically untouchable. The interface also can't be changed as it is part of BCL

Comment: That's ***the*** way to do it in C#.

Comment: Implement `ICloneable` in `BaseAbstract` instead and you only have to implement it once.

Comment: But if the return types match perfectly, then we can implement both in a single implementation. So I was wondering why not even if the return types are different but are    base-derived classes (BaseAbstract  implements System.Object)

Comment: You can't use one method like that. .NET 5 and C#9 added covariant return types for virtual methods, but interface members aren't included in that.

Comment: Barring any other unmentioned restrictions, you could introduce a new abstract base class (between `BaseAbstract` and `Derived`) that implements `ICloneable` for the rest of the class hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

In general answer is **NO**.

Updated:
with custom interface one can but as comments suggests not recommended.

```
public abstract class BaseAbstract
{
    public abstract BaseAbstract Clone();
}

public interface ICloneable<T>
{
    T Clone();
}

public class Derived : BaseAbstract, ICloneable<BaseAbstract>
{
    public override BaseAbstract Clone()
    {
        return new Derived();
    }
}
```

If it BCL interface, explicit interface implementation is only way (already in OP example).

Comment: This `ICloneable<T>` is not the same as `ICloneable` that existing code (not under OP's control) knows how to use / is already using.

Comment: As I understand only ```BaseAbstract``` is not changable.

Comment: `ICloneable` is part of the BCL, so it's also not changeable. If `BaseAbstract`-derived classes are being given to a framework (like the framework that defines `BaseAbstract`), and that framework needs to be able to clone objects it's been given, it's going to look for `ICloneable` (perhaps with an `is` or `as` test). Granted, we don't know how this is being used, but side-stepping a well-known BCL interface means that anything trying to use it can't use it. If OP could use this custom interface, I'd say there's a good chance this question wouldn't have been posted.

Comment: Suggesting to replace non-generic interface with a generic one (without any explanations and warnings) is *not ideal* at best.

Comment: @madreflection you right, if we consider interface as BCL it make sense. I get confused as OP explicitly shows interface definition it his question.

Comment: Sorry, the ICloneable in my question is part of BCL. Will update the question.